# Connection fails with mysql using GoLang

Tags: mysql, go

I am trying to connect the MySql DB using Go Language and gives me following error.

```
sql: unknown driver "mysql" (forgotten import?)
```

My Code

```
package main

    import (
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
    )

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "astaxie:astaxie@/test?charset=utf8")
    checkErr(err);
    err=db.Ping();
}
```

Also when I import

```
        _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

I am getting error of

```
imported and not used
```

Comment: what does your code look like when you add  `_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"`? It shouldn't give imported and not used when you put underscore before package name.

Answer (score 45):

For others coming to this page as a result of the error *sql: unknown driver "mysql" (forgotten import?)*, the `database/sql` package must be used in conjunction with a **database driver**. That means in addition to importing the `database/sql` package, **you need to import a database driver**.

For example, for mysql, you could use the package [go-sql-driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql). Typically, you import this package using the underscore `_` notation, meaning it is imported for its side effects only:

```
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

You can read more about this and find a list of SQL drivers below:

- https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/
- https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SQLDrivers

Comment: Why do we need this driver?

Comment: Because `database/sql` does not provide an implementation for specific sql databases, only a generic interface -- the driver implements the logic that interfaces with the specific database, in this case mysql (handling connections to the database, executing queries, preparing statements, etc)

Comment: perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Try it again, but look for my NOTEs:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)
// NOTE - I removed the import for "fmt" because it was unused.

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "astaxie:astaxie@/test?charset=utf8")
    checkErr(err);
    err=db.Ping();
    // NOTE - the above line will trigger an error because err is unused.
}
```

I added the import for the MySQL driver and removed "fmt" because it was unused.   This may be the cause of your "imported and not used" error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to recheck the location of the packages. I made such a mistake when I manually added this package to the project. It is best to clean GOROOT and GOPATH from this package and reinstall/reconnect it as indicated in the source:
https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql